# Non-unique factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, prime-factorization

I want to show that the decomposition into irreducible factors in the ring

$$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] = \{a + b\sqrt{-5}|\space a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

is not unique, except for the order of factors and for elements being associated with each other.

Now I know that $6 = 2 · 3 = (1 + \sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$ and these are two different decompositions indeed. But how can it be shown that all of these factors are irreducible?

It might also be useful to know what the units of this ring are. Surely 1, -1 are units. But are there other ones, or are these the only ones?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you have the units. To show these are the only units, the norm will be useful. Same for proving irreducibility.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Which norm do I need? My initial thought was to write $2, 3, (1 ± \sqrt{-5}) = (a + b\sqrt{-5})(c+d\sqrt{-5})$ and to somehow rearrange that to show that one of both terms on the RHS must be a unit. But I'm open to other suggestions aswell.

Comment: What you are trying will work, but it is easier to use the norm. In this ring, the suitable norm is $N(a+b\sqrt{-5})=a^2+5b^2$. The crucial property (it is usually proved very early) is $N(xy)=N(x)N(y)$ for $x,y$ in the ring. The norm of $2$ is $4$. If $xy=2$ then $N(x)N(y)=4$. It is easy to see that nothing has norm $2$. So one of $x$ or $y$ must have norm $1$ and the other norm $4$. But $N(w)=1$ iff $w$ is a unit.

Comment: By the way, you don't want to prove that none of $2,3,1+\sqrt{-5},1-\sqrt{-5}$ is irreducible, you want to show they are **all** irreducible.